# On GridView_RowEdititng Pass Selected Column value in session

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdmod" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Data Found" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    SkinID="prgGrid1" AllowPaging="True" BorderColor="Maroon" BorderWidth="2px" Width="600px">
        <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Code">
                <ItemStyle Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="9pt" HorizontalAlign="center" />
                <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" Font-Bold="true" HorizontalAlign="center" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCode" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Code") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Modify/Edit">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnmodify" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" src="../Images/edit.gif" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle Font-Size="10pt" Font-Names="Arial"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle Font-Size="9pt" Font-Names="Arial"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

On `GridView.RowEdititng` event I want to pass the Column Value in session.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

your aspx page like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdmod" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Data Found" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        SkinID="prgGrid1" AllowPaging="True" BorderColor="Maroon" 
        BorderWidth="2px" Width="600px" onrowediting="grdmod_RowEditing">
        <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Code">
                <ItemStyle Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="9pt" HorizontalAlign="center" />
                <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" Font-Bold="true" HorizontalAlign="center" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCode" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Code") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblECode" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Code") %>' />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Modify/Edit">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnmodify" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" src="../Images/edit.gif" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle Font-Size="10pt" Font-Names="Arial"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle Font-Size="9pt" Font-Names="Arial"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

and cs file like this:

```
  protected void grdmod_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    grdmod.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    fillgrd();
    Label l = (Label)grdmod.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lblECode");
    string val = l.Text;
    Session["NAME"] = val;
}
```